# phpbb 3.1 passing variable between 2 pages

Tags: php, phpbb3

With phpbb3.1 it appears they have disabled more superglobals.
I have tried passing a variable between using sessions, but have had no success.

```
$_SESSION['example'] = 'example';
$example = $_SESSION['example'];
```

Nothing is stored because nothing is there due to phpbb disabling superglobals. What's the next best and most secure way to pass variables in between pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if `$_SESSION` is included, but try phpBBs `request` class...

`$example = $request->variable('example','');`

Docs for the class are here - https://wiki.phpbb.com/PhpBB3.1/RFC/Request_class

Comment: No it doesn't, I found out to add a new session variable in phpbb I have to add a new row to the database and add some code to a couple php files. However, this is how you request cookies and url queries in phpbb. So if the data you want to send over to the next page is not something you want to keep private, you could absolutely use this.

Comment: You can also use it to access `$_POST` values too if thats any help

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40334888/1233379), where I explained that you can also temporarily (or globally) switch *Superglobals* back:

**Globally**

Open the `/phpbb/config/parameters.yml` file and change the  **core.disable_super_globals** key from `true` to `false`.

**Programmatically**

This is a sample code that can be used to temporarily enable superglobals (*per-request* scope):

```
// temporarily enable superglobals
$request->enable_super_globals();

// TODO: do your stuff here.

// disable superglobals again
$request->disable_super_globals();
```

You can also read [this blog post](http://www.ryadel.com/en/phpbb-turn-off-deactivated_super_global-option-and-use-server-variables/) that I wrote on this topic for further info.

Comment: 3.2 update: phpbb/config/default/container/parameters.yml